# One sentence with the verb ground

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, verbs

I'm trying to understand the difference between `to land` and `to ground`. We use to ground to say that a plane stopped from flying (or taking off) due to some reason (e.g. engine troubles). Is it correct to say

> The plane was grounded as the engine had crashed on the runway.

Is it grammatically correct and sounds OK?

Comment: It sounds like an engine fell off a wing and came to a complete stop on the tarmac.

Comment: @lurker well, that's slightly different from what I meant, but OK as well. I was thinking about some engine troubles diagnosed during taking off, therefore preveting an accident. So is it grammatically correct and it's OK to say so?

Comment: generally, grounding means that the plane is not functional and is incapable of flying. But you've put it on a runway, Technically its not flying, but it has attempted a flight. So this is a gray area.

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grounded) defines *'grounded'* as :

> prohibit or prevent (a pilot or an aircraft) from flying.

So yes, your sentence construction sounds okay to me. 
 To be *'Grounded'* means that the plane **did not take flight** and then landed back due to some problem. It means that the plane, on development of a technical problem or due to weather problems, **did not even take off**. But *'to land'* means that a flight that **has been in the air**, no matter how long, comes back to the airport (or wherever), due to some fault or as a precautionary measure, or simply, on reaching its destination. 
Also, a 'landed' plane can take off immediately, where as a grounded plane can only take off after the reason behind it has been resolved. 
(Not that a faulty plane that has landed can take off immediately, but a plane that is fully-functional, which has landed, has the capability to take off again.)

Answer (score 1):

*Ground*, when used as a verb, can mean general *to keep attached to the ground* or *to disallow/prevent from leaving.*  (It's also the past participle of *grind*).

The term is used with aircraft and teenagers - a grounded teenager is not allowed to leave his/her room or house.

If a aircraft/teenager has already left, well, you failed to ground it, and your opportunity to ground it again won't be until the aircraft/teenager returns.

When an aircraft contacts the ground at the end of a flight, that is *landing*.  If it can't fly again for some reason, then it is considered *grounded*.